# Object reference comparison in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I'm recently trying to get deep into how ReactJS, and Redux works in terms of when do their hooks update.

Consider the playaround I've made:

```js
let state = { a: 1 };

//action happens, but no change
//comparison

const prevState = state;

state = state;

const nextState = state;

const equal = prevState === nextState ? "Yes" : "No";

console.log("Action - no change. Are they equal?", equal);
```

The above example is simple, both pointing to the same object.

See next example:

```js
let state = { a: 1 };

//action happens, change in state
//comparison

const prevState = state;

state = { ...state, b: 2 };

const nextState = state;

const equal = prevState === nextState ? "Yes" : "No";

console.log("Action - no change. Are they equal?", equal);
```

Although it makes sense now how comparison works for the hooks, but not completely why.

We're changing state, the object itself, but it will be the same reference no matter what value it gets right? So what am I understanding wrong? Is object reference for the value, or declaration, or both?

Comment: `state = { ...state, b: 2 };` creates a new object and assigns a reference to it to `state`. That means it won't be a reference to the same object as `prevState`. It's really not very clear what you're asking here.

Comment: It's quite simple: in the second case you construct an object a second time. An object literal *always* represents a new object, no matter what.

Comment: Note that if your `state` object has nested non-primitives, like `let state = { ob: {} }`, then `prevState.ob === state.ob` after the mutation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We're changing state, the object itself,

No, that code isn't.  Specifically

> ```
> state = { ...state, b: 2 };
> ```

allocates a new, referentially distinct object that is initialized with properties from the previous referent of `state`.

That line isn't changing the object itself; it's assigning a distinct object reference to the cell `state`.

To change the content of state, you could do

```
state.b = 2;
```

which will work as long as the property referred to by `state.b` doesn't exist as an own property, is configurable, or there's a setter on the prototype chain.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare two different object references.  In Javascript, `===` compares if they are the exact same object (meaning same location in memory).

You are doing the equivalent of this in the second example

```
const obj1 = {a: 1};
const obj2 = {a: 1};
obj1 === obj2; // False
```

These will never equal each other as they reside in two different locations in memory.

You can read more about that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Strict_equality_using